# Profiling Serial communication using timeit

Tags: python, time, serial-port, timeit

I need to communicate with an embedded system over RS232. For this I want to profile the time it takes to send a response to each command.

I've tested this code using two methods: `datetime.now()` and `timeit()`

**Method #1**

```
def resp_time(n,msg):
  """Given number of tries - n and bytearray list"""

  msg = bytearray(msg)
  cnt = 0
  timer = 0 

  while cnt < n:
      time.sleep(INTERVAL)

      a = datetime.datetime.now()
      ser.flush()
      ser.write(msg)

      line = []
      for count in ser.read():
          line.append(count)
          if count == '\xFF':
              # print line
              break

      b = datetime.datetime.now()
      c = b-a
      # print c.total_seconds()*1000
      timer = timer + c.total_seconds()*1000
      cnt = cnt + 1

  return timer/n
ser = serial.Serial(COMPORT,BAUDRATE,serial.EIGHTBITS, serial.PARITY_NONE, serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=16)
  if ser.isOpen():
    print "Serial port opened at: Baud:",COMPORT,BAUDRATE

 cmd = read_file()
 # returns a list of commands [msg1,msg2....]
 n = 100
 for index in cmd: 

   timer = resp_time(n,index)
   print "Time in msecs over %d runs: %f " % (n,timer)
```

**Method #2**

```
def com_loop(msg):

  msg = bytearray(msg)

  time.sleep(INTERVAL)
  ser.flush()
  ser.write(msg)

  line = []
  for count in ser.read():
      line.append(count)
      if count == '\xFF':
          break
if __name__ == '__main__':
  import timeit 

  ser = serial.Serial(COMPORT,BAUDRATE,serial.EIGHTBITS, serial.PARITY_NONE, serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=16)
  if ser.isOpen():
    print "Serial port opened at: Baud:",COMPORT,BAUDRATE

  cmd = read_file()
  # returns a list of commands [msg1,msg2....]
  n = 100
  for index in cmd: 

     t = timeit.timeit("com_loop(index)","from __main__ import com_loop;index=%s;" % index,number = n)
     print t/100
```

With datetime I get **2 milli-sec** to execute a command & with timeit I get **200 milli-sec** for the same command.

I suspect I'm not calling `timeit()` properly, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume 200µs is closer to the truth, considering your comport will have something like 115200baud; assuming messages are 8 bytes long, transmitting one message would take about 9/115200 s ~= 10/100000 = 1/10,000 = 100µs on the serial line alone. Being faster than that will be pretty impossible.

Python is definitely not the language of choice to do timing characterization at these scales. You will need to get a logic analyzer, or work **very** close to the serial controller (which I hope is directly attached to your PC's IO controller and not some USB devices, because that will introduce latencies in the same order of magnitude, at least). If you're talking about microseconds, the limiting factor in measurement is usually the random time it takes for your PC to react to an interrupt, the OS to run the interrupt service routine, the scheduler to continue your userland process, and then starts python with its levels and levels of indirection. You're basically measuring the size of single grains of sand by holding a banana next to them.

Comment: Yes theoretically it should be around 200µs (115200,8N1). However a response is sent after the embedded core executes the command, so I think it might be slightly higher.
Python was the fastest to implement, hence the choice. I would be happy if I could get the correct order of magnitude for the timing.

Comment: so if sending alone takes 200µs, it's pretty obvious that both results are wrong. I really recommend a logic analyzer, or at least a digital oscilloscope looking at the RX line